# "Inspection of A and B is/are already done"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

My friend wrote:

> Inspection of Indian Embassy and Bangladesh Embassy is already done. Rest of the inspection is expected soon!

I think the first sentence is ungrammatical, the *is* must be an *are* instead. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your main question, the verb is fine. If you took out the subordinate clause, you'd be left with "Inspection is already done."

However, I can understand your confusion, as it might also be reasonable to say "Inspection*s* are already done."

The key here is whether there is one inspection which happens to cover two places, or two inspections. Either view is reasonable.

The second sentence could use an article, though: "*The* rest of the inspection is expected soon!"

Answer (score 0):

Inspections of both the Indian embassy and the Bangladeshi embassy are complete, with further inspections due for completion....

Inspections are complete for both the Indian embassy and the Bangladeshi embassy, with further inspections due for completion....

Inspection is complete for both the Indian embassy and the Bangladeshi embassy, with further inspection due for completion....

Comment: Thank your sir,got that.one more question -Naming list and voucher are received.right? naming list and voucher is received - it is incorrect right?

Comment: @NBR please do not ask unrelated follow-up questions in comments. Also, note that in English you must put a whitespace after a period or a comma.